# Insert data to Google sheets in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to save a post request data to a google spreadsheet. However, the data is saved as undefined.

The original post uses a form and uses jquery. See the link below. But I'm trying to pass an array also without the use of jquery.

I'm using the following app script without using jquery - https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

I'm posting the code here.

```
function sendData(data) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
    var theUrl = "spreadsheeturl";
    xmlhttp.open("post", theUrl);
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, you have to uncomment a block in the app script if you are passing JSON data.